# Как разбить размеченный текст без знаков препинания на предложения?

Tags: алгоритм

Дан размеченный текст на русском языке со снятой омонимией (т.е. каждому слову соответствует единственный набор характеристик: "часть речи, число, и т.д."), но без каких-либо знаков пунктуации. Необходимо разделить этот текст на предложение, т.е. расставить хотя бы точки.

Так же имеется размеченный корпус, на котором можно произвести обучение, если придумать, что и как обучать.

Каким образом можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: IMHO этот вопрос лучше задать на форуме [Русский язык](http://russ.hashcode.ru/).

(а потом поделиться здесь с нами полученными знаниями).

Comment: думаю. однозначно. проблема. не разрешается.  
казнить. нельзя. помиловать.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос больше подходит для форума Русский язык (http://russ.hashcode.ru/)